# I downloaded a GreasyFork script without Tampermonkey

Tags: tampermonkey

I straight up just downloaded a GreasyFork script. Just hit the download button with no Tampermonkey, no nothing. Now the website I downloaded the script for is now using the script but not in the correct way. How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1):

welcome to stackoverflow,

if you downloaded a js script **WITHOUT** tampermonkey installed,
website **will never** load the js you downloaded

So there is no way the website is using this script, if you didn't load it manually into the website.

Check again if you don't have tampermonkey installed in your browser extensions,
or try to load the website in a private incognito window (Ctrl+Shift+N) without extensions installed.

Comment: I just checked and i found out I had meddle monkey installed too! My mistake! Thanks!